# Default value of xmlns?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

Consider we have the following xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Child />
</Root>
```

As you can see the *Root* does not have default namespace specification. Default namespace is specified with an attribute *xmlns*.

The question is which is the default namespace of such xml document?

If you post an answer could you please also include a reference where information was taken from, e.g. W3C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default schema or namespace in XML.

If you do not declare a namespace in your XML document, it has none.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#concepts):

> For a name N that is not in a namespace, the namespace name has no value.

Comment: sorry, badly formulated my question. I wanted to ask about xmlns.

Comment: @Tim - if you don't declare a namespace, then there are no namespaces in the document.

Comment: Is there such thing as a global namespace?

Answer (score 2):

As Oded notes, there is no such thing as a default schema.

Your `Root` and `Child` elements have no namespace name.

From Namespaces in XML (1.0) Section 6.2 "Namespace Defaulting":

> If there is a default namespace declaration in scope, the expanded name corresponding to an unprefixed element name has the URI of the default namespace as its namespace name. **If there is no default namespace
>   declaration in scope, the namespace
>   name has no value.**